# How can I create new vectors using names from another vector, and appending to each vector in a for loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, vector, append

I have a large dataframe with values in different columns. I also have a vector of names ("prover"), which I want to iterate over, scanning one row ("Analys") in my dataframe for matching values. I then want to select values that are above or below a certain value, and append either 1 or 0 to a set of new vectors, named after the names in my "name vector".

I have tried variations of the below, using paste or paste0 but get different error codes. I have found similar questions here, but haven't managed to get anything I've tried to work. I have also tried lapply (without for loop), but get the following error: "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".

```
for (i in 1:length(prover)){
  if (larm_age$Analys == prover[i]){
    if (larm_age$Ålder >= 18){
      if (larm_age$Res <= ngräns_v || larm_age$Res >= ögräns_v){
        paste(prover[i], sep="") <- 1
      }else{
        paste(prover[i], sep="") <- 0
      }
    }else if (larm_age$Ålder <= 18 && larm_age$Ålder >= 0.1){
      if (larm_age$Res <= ngräns_b || larm_age$Res >= ögräns_b){
        paste(prover[i], sep="") <- 1
      }else{
        paste(prover[i], sep="") <- 0
      }
    }else if (larm_age$Ålder <= 0.1){
      if (larm_age$Res <= ngräns_s || larm_age$Res >= ögräns_s){
        paste(prover[i], sep="") <- 1
      }else{
        paste0(prover[i], sep="") <- 0
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I know there is probably a function somewhere that does this in a way a lot less complicated than what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Generally you can't paste together a variable name and assign to it with `<-`. I can have `ab <- 1`, but `paste("a", "b", sep = "") <- 2` will throw an error. (Though I'm not really sure why you're using `paste` at all.... seems like you are only calling it on length-1 input, so it does nothing). You can use `assign()` to assign a value to a value from a string, but that is usually not needed and a terrible way to write R code.

Comment: Instead, let us help you do this in a more natural way. It will likely be faster to execute, more readable, and more maintainable. But to do that, we need to understand better your problem. Please provide a few rows of sample input and the desired output so we can see what's going on, test solutions, and verify that they get the right answer.

Comment: One easy way to share sample data is with `dput()`. `dput(prover[1:5])` will give copy/pasteable R code to recreate the first 5 elements of `prover`, and `dput(larm_age[1:8, c("Res", "Analys", "Ålder")])` will give copy/pasteable code to create the first 8 rows of `larm_age` for those 3 columns. Please choose a suitable small sample to illustrate the problem. Also please include any other constants needed, like `ögräns_*` and `ngräns_*` values.

Comment: it is likely that you are not using R's capabilities the right way. If you find yourself wanting automating the assignment to vectors and storing information in their object names, this is likely not the way to do it. What about a data frame or list format, where you have a column with the "vector names" and a column with the corresponding "vector values"? (Without having understood your problem at all). It is likely you are looking for something like `dplyr::case_when`.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I unterstand from your question:

You have a column `analys` and a column `alder`.
Let `analys` have the values `a`, `b` and `c`.

I created some simplified example data for you, based on what I am assuming you are trying to achieve.

I think you are trying to categorize the `alder` variable. Then you want to analyse which age groups have what kind of matches in `analys`.
I am leaving out `res` variable, because it is just adding another testing layer.

Computation is cheap, so no need to only calculate categories for matches in `analys`. Make the `category` variable. Then test for matches in `analys` with `prover`. My way of testing might not be the desired solution if `prover` is very big.

I think you wanted to do this as prep work to do another analysis afterwards and again draw conclusions of the different combinations of `prover` matches (represented by `0` and `1` in the test_... columns in this case) and `categories`. You can use `case_when()` for this as well.

If you share a minimum reprex with us, plus desired output, it would be easier to solve your problem :)

In the meantime, I am looking for a solution to automate the `prover` testing without a `for` loop.

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(analys = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), times = 3),
             alder = c(1, 5, 18, 20, 45, 23, 0.05, 0, 0.1),
             id = 1:9)

df |> 
  mutate(category = case_when(alder < 18 & alder >= 0.1 ~ "child",
                              alder >= 18 ~ "grownup",
                              alder < 0.1 ~ "newborn"),
         test_a = case_when(analys == "a" ~ 1,
                            .default = 0),
         test_b = case_when(analys == "b" ~ 1,
                            .default = 0))
```

Results:

```r
  analys alder category test_a test_b
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a       1    child         1      0
2 b       5    child         0      1
3 c      18    grownup       0      0
4 a      20    grownup       1      0
5 b      45    grownup       0      1
6 c      23    grownup       0      0
7 a       0.05 newborn       1      0
8 b       0    newborn       0      1
9 c       0.1  child         0      0
```